# Embedded images in PCL do not show in UWP release build

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I ve found an excellent article on working with images in Xamarin. It mentions an option of embedding images into PCL
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/

I ve built my solution with embedded images in PCL and run it in debug mode under UWP. Images show up fine. Then I ve chosen release build. Application builds and runs fine. However, images are not visible.

To debug, I ve borrowed a code to inspect embedded images.

```
    var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    foreach (var res in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("found resource: " + res);
    }
```

In debug DLL they are all in place. In release build resources are empty. What can be the reason? Any advise is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the suggestion at [Why are my Xamarin UWP Images not showing up on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332132/why-are-my-xamarin-uwp-images-not-showing-up-on-device) (provided by [ArbiterUnknown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6241865/arbiterunknown)) by turning off "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" on the Build tab of Properties for the Release configuration of the main UWP app and it solved my problem.